Does Huawei Backup save SMS messages which are stored on the SIM card?
Does https://play.google.com/store/apps/details/?id=com.huawei.KoBackup
(and in particular version 7.1.1.310_OVE from April 2017) which I understand being the official Huawei backup utility, backup SMS which are stored on the SIM card? I always took for granted the answer is yes, especially because it saves the contacts which are stored on the SIM card, and it doesn't make much sense for a backup utility to miss such important data as SIM sms. However some research revealed that many other SMS backup apps miss these messages, and I couldn't find any explicit info about Huawei backup.
